# "Interesting" examples of exact abelian subcategories of R-Mod

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, abelian-categories

A somewhat vague question: for which rings there exist "interesting" exact abelian subcategories of $R-\operatorname{Mod}$ that are closed with respect to products? Actually, I would like the corresponding functor $D(A)\to D(R-\operatorname{Mod}) $ to possess a left adjoint.

Those that are "not interesting" are the ones that have "simple descriptions in terms of certain projective $R$-modules". I can define this formally; yet something like a full description of all examples in question may allow me to avoid this.

Comment: Are flat modules interesting? What about Gorenstein projective/injective/flat? I feel like there are going to be *too many* interesting exact subcategories closed under product. Have you read about definable classes of modules?

Comment: How about cotorsion abelian groups?

Comment: Flat modules do not give an abelian subcategory. 
However, definable classes may help; thank you!